# How to avoid column name conflict in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, multiple-columns

I am trying to view date of a specific table after joining 3 tables in Laravel. But it shows only one table's information.

Here is the code for joining 3 tables :

**Route File:**

```
 $invoices= DB::table('sales_accounts')
    ->join('invoices', 'sales_accounts.id', '=', 'invoices.sales_Accounts_id')
    ->join('subscribers', 'invoices.receiver_id', '=', 'subscribers.id')
    ->where('sales_accounts.sender_id', $fieldForceID)
    ->get();

return Response::json($invoices);
```

and here is the script for viewing information in Blade Template

**Code In Blade:**

```
function(data) {

            $.each(data, function(index, element) {

                console.log(element);
                infoShare.append("<pre> Date Of Invoice : "+element.created_at+" | Pos Address : "+element.subscriber_address+"| Total Amount: "+element.cost+" </pre>");
            });
        });
```

Here i wanted to view the created date of an **Invoice** but it showed the created date of a subscriber from **subscribers**  table. But i wanted to view specific date of an invoice from invoices table.

How i can i do that? Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it!!!

If i change the joining query like  this, it shows me specific value of a table.

**Query In Route File:**

```
$invoices= DB::table('sales_accounts')
->join('invoices', 'sales_accounts.id', '=', 'invoices.sales_Accounts_id')
->join('subscribers', 'invoices.receiver_id', '=', 'subscribers.id')
->where('sales_accounts.sender_id', $fieldForceID)
->get(['invoices.created_at','invoices.debit','invoices.credit','invoices.cost','subscribers.subscribers_address']);
```

return Response::json($invoices);

Now it works fine!!!

**Updated Query Using SaleAccount Model:**

```
$fieldForceID=Input::get('option');
$invoices= SaleAccount::where('sales_accounts.sender_id', $fieldForceID)
    ->join('invoices', 'sales_accounts.id', '=', 'invoices.sales_Accounts_id')
    ->join('subscribers', 'invoices.receiver_id', '=', 'subscribers.id')
    ->get(['invoices.created_at','invoices.debit','invoices.credit','invoices.cost','subscribers.subscriber_address']);
return Response::json($invoices);
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

Add this on invoices query in **Route File**

```
->addSelect(\DB::raw('invoices.created_At as invoce_created'))
```

Get invoice crated_at date on **Blade File**

```
element.invoce_created
```